# How to prevent users from updating "featurized" settings via the GUI?

Tags: features, configuration, deployment

We have some configuration pages where it is useful for privileged users to be able to see settings that have been exported as part of a feature, but there is no indication on the admin page that those settings have been "featurized." This has resulted multiple times in users changing settings only to realize weeks or months later that the change they had made was inadvertently overwritten during a subsequent code deployment (during the feature revert step).

How can we prevent privileged users from updating a setting in the GUI that have already been exported as part of a feature?

Answer (score 0):

> How can we prevent privileged users from updating a setting in the GUI that have already been exported as part of a feature?

TL;DR: You can't.

Support for that depends on the module's admin implementation. Some modules indicate that the config is overridden by the DB, others do not. Some modules replace the delete with a disable, some do not. Some indicate that the config is from the DB or code, some do not.

What you could do:

- Restrict access to those sections. For instance, it's good to disable `views_ui`, `field_ui` and `context_ui` to prevent "privileged users" to futz around with these settings.
- Assign those users to roles that have more restrictive permissions. Besides, what's the purpose of having them see if they can't/shouldn't do anything with it?
- Tell your users about the possibility of these settings being wiped out and reason with them why.
- Modules are open-source. You can contribute a patch to these modules to add this functionality.